# Придумать логику установки ошибок

Tags: php, база-данных, алгоритм

Есть статья `Article(id, name, status_id)` которая поступила на модерацию. При этом у нее меняется статус: была в черновиках, потом отправлена на ревью, потом либо возвращена либо принята.

Статус - поле в модели статьи, но помимо этого пишется история смены статусов. Типа `ArticleEvent(id, article_id, old_status_id, new_status_id)`.

Также на ревью к статье могут быть установлены ошибки, ну в смысле пометки об ошибках в статье. Это отдельная моделька связанная с ивентом `ArticleError(id, event_id, field_id, message)`. Но ошибки есть только у "ошибочных" ивентов - которые записаны при изменении статуса на "возвращено".

Проблема в следующем: чтобы создать ошибку на этапе ревью мне нужен созданный ивент о возврате статьи чтобы эту ошибку к нему привязать. Но статья то еще не возвращена!!! И не факт что ее вернут, возможно примут. Т.е. мне не к чему привязывать ошибку при установке.

Я пытался делать так: при переходе статьи в статус "ревью" создаю ивент "возвращено" с отдельным полем `is_status_changed` - действительно ли уже изменился статус. Но потом если ошибок все же нет то его надо еще удалять при переходе статьи в статус "принято". И не забывать включать/выключать этот флаг. А еще есть старые статьи со старой историей (раньше это немного по другому было сделано) у которых при статусе "ревью" нет ивента о возврате. Вообщем это чрезвычайно запутано выходит. Очень много багов.

Еще можно наверное создавать ивент о возврате при создании первой ошибки, но ошибки могут еще и удалять (вдруг ошибочно создали), а значит и ивент надо удалять. Так что это еще запутаннее выйдет.

Подскажите как мне лучше это реализовать?

Comment: `"И не факт что ее вернут, возможно примут. Т.е. мне не к чему привязывать ошибку при установке."` - Возможно, в этом случае вам и сами ошибки не нужны? И потом, если вы статью гоняете туда-сюда, правите (иначе зачем ревью, модерация и ошибки), вам нужно версионирование статей. Вот к версиям и привязывайте ошибки.

Comment: *Проблема в следующем: чтобы создать ошибку на этапе ревью мне нужен созданный ивент о возврате статьи чтобы эту ошибку к нему привязать. Но статья то еще не возвращена!!!* Фигня какая-то. У тебя есть ревизии статьи. Каждая смена статуса сопровождается увеличением ревизии. Именно к определённой ревизии привязывается твоя ошибка - и пофиг, какой у статьи в этот момент статус. От того, что статья не возвращена, она не перестала быть статьёй. А ты делаешь так, как будто изменение атрибута статуса делает статью экземпляром другой сущности.

Comment: Можно немного подробнее о том что вы подразумеваете под версиями/ревизиями? Что это будут за сущности и как связаны?

Comment: Разные версии одной статьи. Автор написал статью "Вася Пупкин - редиска", отправил редактору. Редактор прочитал, написал отзыв - "исправить редиска на нехороший человек". Автор переписал статью и заменил везде "редиску" на "нехорошего человека". Вот у вас вторая версия. Ошибка ("употребление слова редиска") относится только к первой версии, во второй ее нет.

Comment: @Dmitry вы предлагаете вести ту же самую историю что у меня, только без указания статусов?

Comment: Я не заметил, где у вас сохраняются версии текстов статей. Я вижу только сохранение истории статусов. Если вы имели в виду, что тексты старых версий статей тоже сохраняются, то, как мне кажется, вам не удалось донести эту мысль. И кстати, я не предлагал отказаться от хранения статусов.

Comment: @Dmitry нет. Тексты старых версий не сохраняются. Текст статьи хранится в модели статьи. На самом деле модерируется далеко не только текст, есть еще куча связанных моделей которые надо модерировать. Например что статью в нужный раздел запостили или что все оплачено верно. Я не понял что вы имели ввиду. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось проще некуда. Я стал привязывать ошибки не к ивенту о возврате, а к ивенту о ревью. Даже странно что я сразу об этом не подумал! :D

Answer (score -1):

В твоём случае вижу только один вариант - создать промежуточный статус, который устанавливать статье при её проверке(ревью).
Т.е. статья поступила на ревью и изменила свой `status_id`. В истории действий `ArticleEvent`создаётся запись к которой и привязываем ошибки, если они есть.

Так же предлагаю задать самому себе вопросы, которые помог придумать конечную логику:

1. Не вижу смысла удалять ивент "Ревью" если нет ошибок. Действией
   было? Было -значит надо отразить в истории.
2. Как будешь использовать ошибки - от этого зависит логика их получения и обработки
3. Почему ты не разберёшься в старой логике и не используешь её? Если это только твоё желание и несет прямой пользы - не выдумывай велосипедов.

Comment: Чем это отличается от описанного мной поведения? О_о

1. Ивент "ревью" не удаляется. Речь шла об удалении ивента "возврат" если статью не стали возвращать, а приняли.